# How to set "DT::renderDataTable" that I can copy or print all of the table not noly one page?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

This is my code, I want copy or print all, but it only print current page, thank you!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("tt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  iris2 = head(iris, 20)
  output$tt <- DT::renderDataTable(
    iris2,
    extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
      dom = 'Bfrtip',
      buttons = c('copy', 'print')
    )
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the option `server = FALSE`.

```
  output$tt <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris2,
      extensions = 'Buttons', 
      options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = c('copy', 'print')
      )
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
```